# GNU find - list directories not containing subdirectory named foo

Tags: find

##### What I have:

I have following file structure created using `mkdir dir{1..5} && mkdir dir{1,3,4}/foo`

```
├── dir1
│   └── foo/
├── dir2
├── dir3
│   └── foo/
├── dir4
│   └── foo/
└── dir5
```

##### What I want:

I want to use the GNU `find` command to list directories that do not contain the `foo/` directory.

My only idea so far:

```
$ find . -type d -name 'foo' -exec dirname {} \; && echo '---' && find . -maxdepth 1 -type d
./dir1
./dir4
./dir3
---
.
./dir1
./dir4
./dir3
./dir2
./dir5
```

And then manually compare them, but there has to be a better way!

Comment: you can automate comparisons with `comm`, but that's not what you would do in this context :)

Answer (score 1):

You'd probably just use your shell (which is GNU `bash` or a better shell like `zsh` if you have access to GNU `find`, most probably) to walk through the directory:

```bash
# /-----+----- "for" loop: for iteration variable chosen from list after "in"
# |     |   
# |  /-------- iteration variable is called "dir" 
# |  |  |   
# |  |  |  /-- choose from list of all directories
# |  |  |  |
# v  v  v  v  
for dir in */ ; do
  [[ -d "${dir}/foo" ]] || echo "${dir}"
# ^^ ^^              ^^ ^^
#  \  |              /  |
#   --------+--------   |
#     |     |           |
#     |     \-------------  [[ ]] : check for condition
#     |                 |
#     \-------------------  -d : condition "path exists and is directory"
#                       |
#                       \-  || if condition fails, do what is after this

done
```

Comment: Wow I completely love the way you explained your answer, really awesome work! But the task was to do it with `GNU find`^^ Still really nice answer, definitely deserves an upvote :)

Comment: yeah, but your problem is simply not a problem for GNU `find`, to be honest; doing it with `find` will unnecessarily complicate (and due to process invocations, and superfluous directory listings) slow down things.

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -type d -a  ! -exec /usr/bin/test -e "{}/foo" \; -print
```

Prints a directory name only if there no 'foo' fine in the directory.

Comment: It doesn't work on my end. It still prints all directories^^

Comment: @Bog this works for me, so you'll have to debug this on your end